# Bindings for source code when debugging in gdb/gud

Tags: key-bindings, debugging, minor-mode, gdb, gud

We can define a bunch of bindings for gud-mode through `gud-mode-map`. But it seems these bindings only hold when the active window is one of the dedicated gdb windows (or simply the comint window if you're not using many-windows).

I can't find any keymap that is active for the source code being debugged -- the only minor mode that seems to be active is gdb-many-windows-mode. That does not have a keymap however. So I tried redefining it:

```
(define-minor-mode gdb-many-windows
  "Redefine many windows to include a keymap"
  :global t
  :group 'gdb
  :version "22.1"
  :keymap my-customized-gdb-mode-map
  (if (and gud-comint-buffer
           (buffer-name gud-comint-buffer))
      (ignore-errors
        (gdb-restore-windows))))
```

But then I realized this is an always-active global mode. So how would I go about customizing keybindngs that are active for the source buffer??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The right place is `gud-minor-mode-map`.

I have got the following bindings in my setup. Pick whatever suits you for your setup.

```el
(defun gdbTZA-gud-run-or-cont (arg)
  "Combination of `gud-run' and `gud-cont'.
If the debugged program is already running use `gdb-cont' and use `gdb-run' otherwise."
  (interactive "p")
  (if (assoc-string gdb-inferior-status '("breakpoint-hit"
                                          "end-stepping-range"
                                          "watchpoint-trigger"
                                          "read-watchpoint-trigger"
                                          "access-watchpoint-trigger"
                                          "function-finished"
                                          "location-reached"
                                          "watchpoint-scope"
                                          "signal-received"))
      (gud-cont arg)
    (gud-run arg)))

(define-key gud-minor-mode-map (kbd "<f4>") #'gud-print)
(define-key gud-minor-mode-map (kbd "<f5>") #'gdbTZA-gud-run-or-cont)
(define-key gud-minor-mode-map (kbd "S-<f5>") #'gud-kill)
(define-key gud-minor-mode-map (kbd "<f6>") #'gdb-many-windows)
(define-key gud-minor-mode-map (kbd "<f9>") #'gud-break)
(define-key gud-minor-mode-map (kbd "<C-f9>") #'gud-tbreak)
(define-key gud-minor-mode-map (kbd "<f10>") #'gud-next)
(define-key gud-minor-mode-map (kbd "C-<f10>") #'gud-until)
(define-key gud-minor-mode-map (kbd "S-C-<f10>") #'gud-tbreak-jump)
(define-key gud-minor-mode-map (kbd "<f11>") #'gud-step)
(define-key gud-minor-mode-map (kbd "S-<f11>") #'gud-finish)

(easy-menu-add-item gud-menu-map nil ["Run Until" gud-until t] "Finish Function")
(easy-menu-add-item gud-menu-map nil ["Add Break At Regexp" gdbTZA-break-at-regexp t] "Temporary Breakpoint")

(defvar gdbTZA-save-point nil
  "List of buffer and point position before command.")

(defun gdbTZA-gud-clear-point (&rest args)
  (setq gdbTZA-save-point nil))

(defun gdbTZA-gud-save-point (&rest args)
  "Save buffer and point in `gdbTZA-save-point' before a gui command."
  (when (and gud-minor-mode
             (null (eq (current-buffer) gud-comint-buffer)))
    (setq gdbTZA-save-point (list (current-buffer) (point)))))

(defun gdbTZA-gud-restore-point (&rest args)
  "Restore point in buffer from `gdbTZA-save-point'."
  (when (and gdbTZA-save-point
             (buffer-live-p (car gdbTZA-save-point)))
    (with-current-buffer (car gdbTZA-save-point)
      (goto-char (nth 1 gdbTZA-save-point))
      )))

(defun gdbTZA-gud-goto-arrow (&rest args)
  "Follow marker even if it goes off screen."
  (when (markerp gud-overlay-arrow-position)
        (with-current-buffer (marker-buffer gud-overlay-arrow-position)
          (goto-char gud-overlay-arrow-position))))

(advice-add #'gud-call :before #'gdbTZA-gud-clear-point)
(advice-add #'gud-print :after #'gdbTZA-gud-save-point)
(advice-add #'gud-break :after #'gdbTZA-gud-save-point)
(advice-add #'gdb-done :after #'gdbTZA-gud-restore-point)

(defun gdbTZA-gdb-mode-hook-function ()
  "Add `gud-tbreak-jump' to the list of gud-gdb functions."
  (gud-def gud-tbreak-jump (if (not (string-match "Disassembly" mode-name))
                   (progn
                 (gud-call "-exec-tbreak %f:%l" arg)
                 (gud-call "-exec-jump %f:%l" arg))
                 (save-excursion
                   (beginning-of-line)
                   (forward-char 2)
                   (gud-call "-exec-tbreak *%a" arg)
                   (gud-call "-exec-jump *%a" arg)))
       "\C-J" "Advance to current line or address."))

(add-hook 'gdb-mode-hook #'gdbTZA-gdb-mode-hook-function)
```